# How to enable standard C++ 14/17 in Intel C++ compiler?

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17, intel-parallel-studio, intel-composer

Programming Environment:

- Visual Studio 2017(15.6.2)
- Intel Parallel Studio Xe 2018 Update 1
- Windows 10(6299.309)

My problem is that I cannot include latest headers like `std::variant` and `std::optional` with latest Intel C++ 18 update 1 version.

Say if I include `std::variant` for an instance, the compiler yelling with this error even if add `-std=c++17` or `/Qstd=c++17` compiler options:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\include\variant(16): error : #error directive: class template variant is only available with C++17.
1>   #error class template variant is only available with C++17.
```

Comment: I shouldn't have to go off-site to get more information about your question. Post what's relevant here.

Comment: @Drise I added that intel link  I have attached some images there that's why... I will attached them here too... it will conveinient to someone.

Comment: I highly encourage you to ***not*** post the images, and instead *describe* the issue. If those image links ever die, your question is right back to where it is now.

Comment: I think for some of the C++17 features you need specifiy latest instead of c++17 but that's for the MSVS compiler.

Comment: @Drise thank you for editing pal... appreciated

Comment: @NathanOliver MSVC okay but Intel compiler keeps bothering ,,,